# What is the correct way to sanatise plastic pet bottles?

Tags: sanitation, bottles, plastic, beginner

I just bought a couple of boxes of plastic bottles for my first home brew. I assume that they are clean being new, but I need to sanatise them.

I have a no rinse sanatise solution, should I use that?  But do you rinse it after to remove any potential taste?

Also I do not have a bottle tree so what happens if there is water in the bottles, or should I wait until 100% dry?

Chris

Comment: Most no-rinse sanitizers only work when they're wet, so you want to bottle before the sanitizer dries.

Answer (score 1):

If the sanitizing solution is no rinse, you shouldn't rinse it...that's what "no rinse" means!  If you rinse you pretty much negate the effect of your sanitizer.  There is no need for the bottles to dry before using.  Just drain out as much liquid as possible.

Comment: Thanks, since it is my first brew just wanting to get it rIght. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would clean out the bottles even if they are new. You spend a bit of time and effort making your brew so for the fact of a few minutes I would clean them to make sure you don't have any off flavors or bad batches that may have been picked up from the factory or supplier.

With the no rinse solution as Denny says there it no need to rinse. Rinsing them has a chance that you will make the bottles un-sanitized. Drain as best you can then the amount left in the bottles is not enough to impart any flavors or affect the brew in any way.

FYI with the no rinse solution I have a brother in-law that does not like to leave the no rinse in there and will rinse with the bottles very hot water then put the caps on them straight after rinsing and his brews come out fine. In my opinion I wouldn't waste my time rinsing.